# Cannot run same code on google colab (tensorflow read_file error)

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

```
/content/drive/My Drive/DnCNN-tensorflow-master/model.py:233 im_read  *
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py:568 read_file  **
    "ReadFile", filename=filename, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:493 _apply_op_helper
    (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))

TypeError: Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string.
```

I run same code on my pc but cannor run on Google colab. What should i do?

Comment: where is this `file` stored and also please share the code you  are using?

Comment: '
def im_read(filename):
    """Decode the png image from the filename and convert to [0, 1]."""
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=3)
   
I'm using that code block for it. File is an image to train.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the name of your file is not in the expected string format. Just renaming your file with os.rename, should solve the problem.